# Pig latin translating program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, pig-latin

About 2 months ago I started studying python and then 3 days ago sat and began to write a program (found the dumbest & simplest thought I could: a pyglatin translator). I finally got it working 100%. Being a beginner I would love to hear some constructive criticism on my program; I know I have probably written more then was needed on some stuff and taken a long way around on others.

```
another_word = " "
sentence1 = " "
new_list = []
another = " "



def trans_one_word (i):
    global another_word
    pyg = 'ay'

    original = (i)

    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[0]
        new_word = word + first + pyg
        another_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
        return another_word
    else:
        print('empty')


def input_state():

    sentence = input("enter a word to be translated: ")
    list = sentence.split()
    for i in list:
        trans_one_word(i)
        new_list.append(another_word)
    s = " "
    print (s.join( new_list ))


input_state()


another = input("Would you like to enter another sentence to be     translated? \n Y/N")

if (another == 'y') or (another == 'Y'):
    input_state()
```

All in all I am proud of myself for actually writing it without any help, or all of it except the last "if" statement (I had minor problems with it).

Answer (score 5):

Some comments on your code. Overall you are using a lot of unnecessary variables.

```
another_word = " "
sentence1 = " "
new_list = []
another = " "
```

You really don't need these variables declared outside of your functions, they add no value and just pollute the namespace.

```
def trans_one_word (i):
```

PEP8 doesn't recommend a  before the args. And you should consider having more meaningful arg names.

```
    global another_word
```

Unnecessary global, you are returning this variable from the function so don't need it to be global

```
    pyg = 'ay'

    original = (i)
```

Parens are unnecessary and you could just call the arg `original` as you don't need this assignment.

```
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[0]
        new_word = word + first + pyg
        another_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
```

You don't need `len(new_word)` on a slice an empty slice implies to the end of the word, e.g. `new_word[1:]`

```
        first = word[0]
        new_word = word + first + pyg
        another_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
        return another_word
```

This whole block can be simplified to `return word[1:] + word[0] + pyg`

```
    else:
        print('empty')
```

You don't need the `else:` clause because the previous block returned. You should also return the original word.

```
def input_state():

    sentence = input("enter a word to be translated: ")
```

Assume you meant to ask for a words or a sentence given the variable name:

```
    list = sentence.split()
```

`list` is a python type, so shouldn't be used for a variable name.

```
    for i in list:
        trans_one_word(i)
        new_list.append(another_word)
    s = " "
```

You should look into list comprehensions and generators as this can be significantly simplified, e.g. `print(" ".join(trans_one_word(i) for i in sentence.split()))`

```
    print (s.join( new_list ))
```

It's probably better to return this result and let the caller `print` it.

```
input_state()

another = input("Would you like to enter another sentence to be     translated? \n Y/N")

if (another == 'y') or (another == 'Y'):
    input_state()
```

This condition can be replaced with `if another in 'yY':`
You should really put this all into a loop so with an exit clause.

Simplifying the code:

```
def trans_one_word(word):
    pyg = 'ay'

    if word and word.isalpha():
        word = word.lower()
        return word[1:] + word[0] + pyg
    return word

def input_state():
    sentence = input("enter a sentence to be translated: ")
    return " ".join(trans_one_word(word) for word in sentence.split())

while True:
    print(input_state())
    another = input("Would you like to enter another sentence to be translated?\nY/N")
    if another not in 'yY':
        break
```

Comment: Note that the original code would translate one or two sentences. Your solution offers to translate infinitely many sentences.

Comment: I suggest also eliminating `pyg = 'ay'` and writing `return word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'`.

Comment: Yes, a loop structure for the request was part of my feedback, as it was unclear whether the intent was for 1+ vs. just 1 or 2. So an assumption on my part - which may ultimately be incorrect.

Comment: AChampion, certain lines I did the way that I did for my own clarification (to keep it clear in my head). I agree, I should have used a lont of comments rather then coding in the way I did.

Comment: it is simply meant to take one sentence and translate it then ask if you wish to do another sentence. **if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():** I used len(original) > to make sure there was an actual word there or at least a letter. I used original.isalpha() to make sure it was letters and not numbers. print empty if the info entered was either blank or if it was numbers.

Comment: You got me on the "enter a word to be translated" it was suppose to be "enter a sentence to be translated"

Comment: list= sentence.split was done so that the translation block to cycle through each word separately translating them as it went through each of them. The "for i in list" statement was done as such because as I said, I am very very new to programming and did not know how to put it all into one line. I can agree with virtually everything that you said and I thank you for the criticism. I hope this explains quite a bit of why I chose to do things as I did.

Comment: Absolutely, take the feedback for what it's worth. What works for you accept what doesn't ignore. And good luck.

Comment: Thank you AChampion. I always accept constructive criticisim but I am willing to defend my actions as well as my reasonings. I know the comments really should have been there but I just had a sudden flash of light in my head and wanted to get it down fast rather then risk forgetting the flash while I wrote comments hehe. Short memory span is a bitch and a half :P and I totally agree that some did not truly need to be global variables but I am still working on the program. I am attempting to add a function to translate pygLatin to Engh then plan on giving the option to trans to pyg or to Eng.

Comment: After that I plan to attempt to work it all into TKinter and dress it up nice. I honestly do appriciate the comments from you all, they do help.